# How to change style of cf7 in a custom page?

Tags: css, wordpress

I tried to insert a contact form using CF7 into a custom template as follows

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="107" title="enquiry"]')  ?>
```

it will work fine. Then I tried to give custom style to that form. In my style.css I add the following lines:

```
.wpcf7 form {
background-color: #46fb44 !important;
border: 1px solid #f28f27;
padding:20px;
 }
.wpcf7 input[type="text"],
.wpcf7 input[type="email"],
.wpcf7 textarea {
background:#725f4c;
color:#FFF;
font-family:lora, sans-serif;
font-style:italic;
}
.wpcf7 input[type="submit"],
.wpcf7 input[type="button"] {
background-color:#725f4c;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

but nothing will affect. Is there any other way?

Comment: edit your contact us form from admin end and use there the class on level and input

Comment: Can you add a link to your site or test page, or give a sample output of the html.

Comment: why don't you using your own classes/id's. if you need you can use form ID/Class either. First code your form like doing in HTML/CSS. Then translate same Form to the CF7. There is no difference occurring. According to your HTML/CSS coding rarely there were some tweaks. But those are not too hard to fix. That is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css try to put it into your theme editor style.css

```
form.wpcf7-form {
background-color: #46fb44 !important;
border: 1px solid #f28f27;
padding:20px;
 }
.wpcf7 input[type="text"],
.wpcf7 input[type="email"],
.wpcf7 textarea {
background:#725f4c;
color:#FFF;
font-family:lora, sans-serif;
font-style:italic;
}
.wpcf7 input[type="submit"],
.wpcf7 input[type="button"] {
background-color:#725f4c;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
text-transform:uppercase;
color: #fff;
}
textarea.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-textarea {
    width: 807px;
}
input.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text {
    width: 807px;
}
```

and the output is : 
   [image]

working fine on my localhost try to give width in px instead of %

Thanks

Comment: pls remember i try to add the form  into a customTemplate

Comment: yea I know that there will only contact us form shortcode going to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the custom css code for contact form 7 with this example [How to Style Contact Forms in WordPress](https://wpforms.com/how-to-style-contact-forms-in-wordpress/)